# Replacing a character in a scanner string

Tags: java, string, replace

So for an assignment I'm supposed to create a program that doubles every letter and triples every exclamation mark of a phrase that is inputted into a scanner. Here is what I got so far:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class DoubleLetters{
  public static void main(String[]args){
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter a statement");
    String x = scan.nextLine();
    String y = x.replace("! ","!!! ");
    for(int j=0; j< x.length(); j++){
      System.out.print(y.charAt(j));
      System.out.print(y.charAt(j));
    }
  }
}
```

Doubling the letters work, but not tripling the exclamation marks. I tried to use the replace method and it did not work. Please, any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add if statement inside a loop

```
if(y.charAt(j) == '!') {
   System.out.print(y.charAt(j));
}
```

and remove empty spaces in replace method

```
String y = x.replace("!","!!!");
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
String y = x.replace("!","!!!");
```

or  this

```
    for (char c : x.toCharArray()) {
        System.out.print(c);
        System.out.print(c);
        if (c == '!') {
            System.out.print(c);
        }
    }
```

Comment: I'm not supposed to be able to use arrays yet and my teacher suggested using the method Character.isLetter(ch) in some way (though I dont necessarily have to) but I don't know in what way

Answer (score 0):

Convert String into **char** array than do double and triplet and display . Start reading from left hand side and move to right hand side using double and triplet condition update char array and finally display result(char array) .

Comment: I don't think I'm allowed to use arrays yet, only conditionals and my professor suggested using the following method(though I don't have to): Character.isLetter(ch) but I don't know in what way

Answer (score 0):

You could go over all the characters and append them to a `StringBuilder`:

```
String str = /* recieved from scanner */
StringBuidler builder = new StringBuilder();

for (char c : str.toCharArray()) {
    // Any character needs to be included at least once:
    builder.append(c);

    // If it's a letter, you need another copy (total of 2)
    if (Character.isLetter(c)) {
        builder.append(c);
    // If it's an excalmation mark, you need another two copies (total of 3)
    } else if (c == '!') {
        builder.append(c);
        builder.append(c); 
   }
}

System.out.println(builder);
```

System.out.print(y.charAt(j));
  System.out.print(y.charAt(j));
}

Answer (score 0):

Try the follwing code, it will work efficiently as you like,

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class DoubleLetters
{
   public static void main(String[]args)
   {
     Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
     System.out.println("Enter a statement");
     String x = scan.nextLine();
     for(int j=0; j< x.length(); j++)
     {
   if(y.charAt(j)=='!')
    System.out.println("!!!");
   else
   {
          System.out.print(y.charAt(j));
          System.out.print(y.charAt(j));
   }
     }
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

As u havn't succeeded to replace '!' . so for a another approach instead of replace you can tokenize your string using StringTokenizer as this piece of code. and by this u can add what u want as for your case at the end of each **!** u can add 2 more **!!**. code as.

```
System.out.println("---- Split by comma '!' ------");
    String s = "My Name !is !Manmohan"; //scanner string
    System.out.println("---- Split by comma ',' ------");
    StringTokenizer st2 = new StringTokenizer(s, "!");
    String now = "";
    while (st2.hasMoreElements()) {
        now += st2.nextElement() + "!!!";
    }

    System.out.println(now.substring(0, now.length() - 3));
            //op ...  My Name !!!is !!!Manmohan
```